# Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/_User/Downloads/gatherwarbot.py", line 66, in on_voice_state_update
    if after.channel.id in [765273249042661427]:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:/_User/Downloads/gatherwarbot.py", line 66, in on_voice_state_update
    if after.channel.id in [765273249042661427]:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

i have this error with this code

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):

    t = time.strftime(f"%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")

    if after.channel.id in [765273249042661427]:

        channel2 = bot.get_channel(772214888474083358)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**{member.mention} `Waiting for donate`**", color=0x85bb65)
        embed = embed.set_footer(text=str(t))
        await channel2.send("**<@&765301837024722964>**", embed=embed)
```

how  can i fix it?

Comment: i still have this error help me plz

Answer (score 0):

If `member` **leaves** a voice channel `after` will be `None`, if the `member` **joins** a voice channel `before` is `None`. Here's how you can fix that:

```py
state = before or after # name it however you want
# Use the `state` variable from now on
```

Comment: ```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
    state = before or after
    t = time.strftime(f"%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")

    if state.channel.id in [765273249042661427]:

        channel2 = bot.get_channel(772214888474083358)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"**{member.mention} `Waiting for donate`**", color=0x85bb65)
        embed = embed.set_footer(text=str(t))
        await channel2.send("**<@&765301837024722964>**", embed=embed) ``` code like this?